# How to make Core Data fetch requests in a class rather than view?

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data, mobile-development

I'm new to Swift. I am now working on a `RecipesModel` which includes functions to read in raw data and create instances of a Recipe class. I also have `IngredientItem` entities saved in my Core Data. During the `createRecipes` function I need to call a fetchRequest to see which `IngredientItems` are in Core Data. However, I recently discovered I cannot use environment variables in classes and therefore **am struggling to source my managedObjectContext** like I did in my Views.

I've tried passing the managedObjectContext from my View -> ViewModel -> Model however this seemed to have some issues and I couldn't get working. Would this be the right approach and if so try again? If not what should I try?

Here's the snippet of code that I'm referring to:

```
    func createRecipes(from jsonData: Data) -> [Recipe] {
        var recipes = [Recipe]()

        do {
            let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as! [String:Any]
            let recipeObjects = jsonObject["recipes"] as! [[String:Any]]

            for recipeObject in recipeObjects {

                let recipeIngredientNames: [String] = recipeObject["ingredients"] as! [String]
                var allIngredientsItemsInCoreData: [IngredientItem] = []

                let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<IngredientItem> = IngredientItem.fetchRequest()
                do {
                    let result = try moc.fetch(fetchRequest)
                    print("IngredientItems found: \(result)")
                    allIngredientsItemsInCoreData = result
                } catch {
                    print("Error fetching IngredientItem entities: \(error)")
                    allIngredientsItemsInCoreData = []
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your approach should work. Another approach if you did include Core Data from the start in your project is to access it from the PersistenceController struct, `PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext`

Comment: *”This seemed to have some issues…”* What issues did you see?

Comment: @TomHarrington 

I am recieving an error on my view init saying "self.recipesViewModel used before being initialised"

My code is like the following:

View: 
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
let recipesViewModel: RecipesViewModel
init() { self.recipesViewModel = RecipesViewModel(moc: moc) }

View Model:

var moc: NSManagedObjectContext
var recipesModel: RecipesModel

init(moc: NSManagedObjectContext) { 
    self.moc =  moc
    self.recipesModel = RecipesModel(moc: managedObjectContext)
}

Model:
Similar to VM with assigning moc to what VM passes to it in init.

Comment: @MarcelQT Your error has to do with something that doesn’t appear anywhere in your question? Am I reading that right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.task` for that, e.g.

```
.task {
    // async download recipes

    // async deserialise json

    // async insert into core data using a background context
}
```

You'll need to handle merging the background context into the view context which can be tricky or just enable `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent`.

Comment: I think I see what you mean but at the same time why would the MVVM architecture exist if this were the case? Isn't having a ViewModel seperate from the View be a better/cleaner architecture to improve seperation of concerns when things get more complex?

Comment: @malhal My interpretation of the code excerpt is that OP fetches ingredients from Core Data to see if the json recipe has existing ingredients or if they need to be created before storing the recipe. This is not the kind of logic you want to put in a view (and not in a view model either).

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks I'll have to fix my answer now!